# Reproject geometry with a QGIS expression

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, qgis-expression

In the QGIS attribute form, I'm trying to convert from NAD83/BC Albers (EPSG:3005) to WGS84 / Pseudo-Mercator (EPSG 4326) with the following code:

```
format_number(
    y(
        transform(
            $geometry,
            'EPSG:3005',
            'EPSG:4326'
        )
    ),
    6
)
```

The process works but I'm getting incorrect coordinates returned. I use identical code lines to successfully transform other CRSs, but obviously I'm messing something up here. I've attached a screengrab that previews the properly formatted resultant 44.199697° that should be more like  49.920942°

[image]

Comment: The EPSG code for Web Mercator is *not* 4326, it's 3857. 4326 is WGS84 decimal degrees.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that the assigned CRS is set to EPSG:3005 and correct the value of your target EPSG.

[image]

You should put this as a default values for your lon/lat fields, respectively :

```
format_number(x( transform( $geometry, layer_property(@layer,'crs'), 'EPSG:4326')),6)
format_number(y( transform( $geometry, layer_property(@layer,'crs'), 'EPSG:4326')),6)
```

Comment: My mistake, needed a coffee I think! I was after decimal degrees (4326) not Pseudo-Mercator (3857), just sated it wrong in my question. This did work, it was the assigned CSR, Thank you!

Comment: This side tries to avoid "thank you" messages. Instead, it encourages you to accept the answer and/or upvote it: click the checkmark right to the answer to accept it - see: https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers
Just click the checkmark, see here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235

Comment: All right, thank you @Babel